# Python colon in lists

Tags: python, list

I was reading the Python documentation on lists and saw:

> `list.extend(L)` Extend the list by appending all the items in the given list. Equivalent to: `a[len(a):] = L.`

I was wondering where I could read about the `:` colon to fully understand it. Python documentation for 3.4 would be very helpful.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/3001761

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Wow apparently I have the authority to close questions without a vote now... such power.

Comment: @AndrewClark gold badge holders can single handedly close a duplicate question. This was implemented some weeks ago

Comment: @TimCastelijns Okay cool!  I was looking around in the reputation privileges wondering why I could do that...